# Anybody know where I can find src for Monorail 2.0.0?

Tags: castle, castle-monorail

We are using that exact version and I believe I've hit a bug that I might need to fix, however the 2.1RC doesn't fix it, and I don't want to break all dependencies to other frameworks (Windsor for instance) for an upgrade.

They have however removed the SVN repository that contained all tags, and the new git repository doesn't contain any tags at all so I have no idea which revision I should check out.

Does anyone know where I can find the source code? I have an old version for 1.0.3 on my drive but that is of little use now...

Comment: Hmm, seems like this is it: https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.MonoRail-READONLY/tags, however I can't build and use it because I get some security issue?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is a memory leak in the rescue handling. ProcessRescue in Controller.cs invokes CreateAndProcessRescueController which creates the controller from the factory, but never releases it. However, I managed to build a patched version now using the 2.0.0 branch and running some tests now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, they seem to have put it in a readonly git repository and branched it for 2.0.0 here:

https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.MonoRail-READONLY/tree/2-0-stable